# When is it necessary to queue the requests from the client

Tags: concurrency, queue

I have heard that there is a limit for a server for the requests number it can process.

So if the requests from the client are large than the number people will queue the requests.

So I have two problems:

1 When

How to decide if it is necessary to queue the requests? How to measure  the largest number?

2 How

If the queue is unavoidable, so where should be the queue done?

For a J2EE application using spring web mvc as the framework, I want to know if the queue should be put in the `Controller` or the `Model` or the `DAO`?

3 Is there a idea which can avoid the queue but keeping providing the service?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to establish your limit at the server actually is. Its likely that its a limit on the frequency of messages, ie. maybe your limited to sending 10 requests a second. If thats the case then your would need to keep a count of how many messages you've sent out in a second, then before you send out a request check to see if you will breach this limit, if this is true then you must make the thread wait until the second is up. If not your free to send the request. This thread would be reading from a queue of outbound messages.

If the server limit is determined in an other way, i.e. dynamically based on its current load, which sounds like it might be in your case, there must be a continuous feed of request limits which you must process to determine the current limit. Once you have this limit you can process the requests in the same way as mentioned in the first paragraph.

As for where to put the queue and the associated logic, i'd put it in the controller.

I don't think there is a way to avoid the queue, you are forced to throttle your requests an therefore you must queue your outbound requests internally so that they are not lost, and will be processed at some point in the future.